# Why my program shows "runtime error (NZEC) edit ideone it" when i run it on spoj

Tags: java

Hi I'm new to programming.I would like to get my hands dirty in spoj.I have tried many problems but i always get "runtime error (NZEC)
edit    ideone it " error though programs seem to work fine on eclipse.I can not get this straight to my head.It is the first step which i am not able to cross.I know it seems to be off-topic.I would appreciate if someone with experience in Spoj can get me though it.It might help others people who are facing same problem.
So the question is

**Multiply the given numbers.**

**Input**
n [the number of multiplications <= 1000]

l1 l2 [numbers to multiply (at most 10000 decimal digits each)]

Text grouped in [ ] does not appear in the input file.

**Output**
The results of multiplications.

Example
Input:

```
5      
4 2     
123 43     
324 342    
0 12    
9999 12345
```

Output:

```
8     
5289    
110808    
0    
123437655
```

My code is

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Main m=new Main();
    m.get();
}

public void get()
{
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    int n=sc.nextInt();
    if(n<=1000)
    {
    sc.nextLine();
    String[] allNum=new String[n];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        allNum[i]=sc.nextLine();
    StringTokenizer st;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        st=new StringTokenizer(allNum[i]," ");
        int a=Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
        int b=Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
        System.out.println(mul(a,b,1));
    }
    }
}
public int mul(int a,int b,int pow)
{
    if(b==0)
    return 0;
    int s=b%10;
    return (a*s)*pow+mul(a,b/10,pow*10);
}
}
```

**Thanks in advance.**

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to read 10K digit number as integer which is incorrect i.e. it would overflow from integer limit. Instead i would use [BigInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) and use `multiply` method to multiply two big numbers.

So your lines here:

```
int a=Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
int b=Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
```

Would change to

```
BigInteger a = new BigInteger(st.nextToken());
BigInteger b = new BigInteger(st.nextToken());
BigInteger result = a.multiply(b);
```

Comment: how to compare   if(b==0)
  return 0;
  int s=b%10;

Comment: You dont need mul method at all.. Just print value of result and you should be done. FYI it would be `if (b.equals(BigInteger.ZERO)) return 0; BigInteger s = b.mod(BigInteger.TEN);`

Comment: Now the time limit exceeds.Screw my life.

Answer (score 0):

The `BigInteger` class allows us to process numbers with many digits N, where N is a considerably high number. Such is the case for multiplication
`int` change their values to `BigInteger`

```
        BigInteger a = new BigInteger(st.nextToken());
        BigInteger b = new BigInteger(st.nextToken());
        BigInteger result = a.multiply(b);
        System.out.println(result);
```

mui his method would thus working with BigInteger

```
public BigInteger  mul(BigInteger  a,BigInteger  b,BigInteger  pow)
{
    if(b.equals(BigInteger.ZERO)) 
        return new BigInteger("0"); 
    BigInteger s = b.mod(BigInteger.TEN);
    BigInteger sx = a.multiply(b).add(pow);
    return (s.multiply(sx).add(mul(a, b.divide(new BigInteger("10")), pow.pow(10))));
}
```

Comment: this gives me "time exceeds".:(

Comment: the error message is that? `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded`